# How to install library with pip-console?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qpython, qpython3

I downloaded some python library package (for example uncompile2) from GitHub. How I can install it into Qpython from the directory in my android device with pip-console? Or at least to try install...

Comment: And how do you install packages at all without manually copying stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You could install it directly through pip console, just type "pip install "

Or, you can make a .sh file with contents

```
python /your/path/to/the/package/setup.py install
```

Or at least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the modules you want installed into the site-packages folder

using a file manager open up the folder: 
`/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` 

that is where you can put the modules, i have not tried it with the pip console.